# Exchange 2003 Database Transfer / Recovery Procedure

Tags: exchange-2003

I was paged early this morning for a dead mail server, the upshot is that the Windows Server install is dead. I've booted the box with the Windows UBCD and have been able to get the database and logs copied onto the network.

What I need is a start to finish guide (or just helpful tips) for building an Exchange 2003 server using the existing database that I have.

I know that Microsoft have a couple of white papers on the subject but for some reason my Google skillz appear to be failing me today.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rebuild Exchange using the `/disasterrecovery` switch

[An overview](http://www.petri.co.il/exchange_disasterecovery_switch.htm) and the [Operations Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125070%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

It appears that the [guide from msexchange.org](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Recovering-Failed-Exchange-2003-Member-Server-Using-Disaster-Recovery-Switch.html) has some more detailed steps

Comment: If memory serves you need to be sure that you install and patch Exchange to the same level as the failed server as well

Comment: That sounds familiar, Paul. Even if it's not required, I'd certainly recommend it

Answer (score 1):

The highlights: Install Exchange on another server. Run eseutil on the DB to be sure it's consistent (I assume the last server didn't gracefully shutdown); repair if necessary (make sure you have a backup copy). Create a Recovery Storage Group, point it to the old database. Mount the DBs in the SG. Use the Mailbox Recovery Center under Tools to associate users with Mailboxes again.

It's fairly easy, I'll see if I can find a better step-by-step guide...

Answer (score 0):

For Exchange 2003 disaster r recovery, follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Have a windows server installed and patched to match existing Exchange server

**Step 2:** Reset Exchange Server Active Directory account

**Step 3:** Install Exchange Server 2003

**Step 4:** [Run Eseutil /mh](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/check-exchange-database-state-using-eseutil-mh-command.php)

**Step 4a:** If clean state, now mount the Store then mail should start flowing.

**Step 4b:** If dirty shutdown, Run ESEUtil /r for soft recovery, now mount the Store then mail should start flowing.

Reference: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2538-exchange-2003-disaster-recovery-quick-and-easy